# How to post the FB comment in my wordpress site to my FB fan page wall?

Tags: facebook, wordpress, facebook-page

I used FB comment on a wordpress site. I want to create a FB Fan page and wanted to post the comment made on my wordpress site in my FB Fan page.

Answer (score 0):

It's achievable only with user's permissions, and it is achievable by creating application, for example